# Qt Creator - cannot find -lGL

Tags: qt-creator

I've just started (today) to use Qt c++ in order to build some GUIs for systems. I'm using the IDE (Qt Creator) on Ubuntu 14.04 and am following the tutorial, that comes packaged with the installation, for creating a Qt widget application - a program to search a text file for a word.

When I try to build and run it I get the error `cannot find -lGL`.

What's the problem, should work out the box if it come with the IDE no?

Comment: Just a guess. Are you missing the library on Ubuntu? OpenGL something?

Answer (score 1):

Just type

```
sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev
```

That should solve this